# The metric $g=dx^2+\cosh^2(x)dy^2$ is complete

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I want prove that the metric $g=dx^2+\cosh^2(x)dy^2$ is complete with constant curvature $-1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for that I considered the following function (suggested in an article) $f:(\mathbb{R}^2,g)\to (\mathbb{R}^2,g_{-1})$, where $g_1=dx^2+e^{2x}dy^2$, defined by $$f(x,y)=(-y+\ln(\cosh x),e^y\tanh x).$$ I gotten to show that this is a diffeomorphism with inverse $$f^{-1}(x,y)=\Big(\sinh^{-1}(ye^x),\ln(\sqrt{e^{-2x}+y^2})\Big),$$ I need to know explicitly how the mentioned function $f$ preserves the metric. This is the Danilo Blanusa's article: [*Über die Einbettung hyperbolischer Räume in
euklidische Räume*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01303796) I'm trying to read in detail this article about the immersion of $\mathbb{H}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ in which I found this metric, I have not been able to find the other article where it mentions the function mentioned.
[image]

Comment: Is $g$ the euclidean metric? If yes, then it cannot be an isometry as the curvature is different.

Comment: @ArcticChar $g$ is given at the top of the question and in the title

Comment: Ar, I misread that as $g_{-1}$, thanks.

Comment: @Zaragosa I have no quick proof (and no time to give a long one) right now, but you can check Lobatchevsky coordinates on your favorite web browser

Comment: What does _I can't get that_ mean? (1) You know the conclusion is false? (2) Something prevents you from checking the condition for being an isometry?

Comment: Your definition should include an explanation of the notation $(\mathbb H^2,g_{-1})$. Presumably that notation refers to the hyperbolic plane, however there are several different models of the hyperbolic plane in common use (the upper half plane; the Poincaré disc; the Beltrami-Klein disc) and you should say exactly which one you mean, including an explanation of the enigmatic $g_{-1}$.

Comment: @Didier when you have time it would be interesting to know what your idea for the test is. I'd be really grateful.

Comment: @LeeMosher that is the problem, in the article it only mentions that this function is an isometry that preserves the metric but it does not mention which of all the models of the hyperbolic plane it is taking.

Comment: Let me suggest, then, that you add some context to your problem, in particular what article you found this statement in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i'm wrong with this but i would appreciate your comment please:
Let $$f(x,y)=(\underbrace{-y+\ln(\cosh x)}_{u},\underbrace{e^y\tanh x}_{v})$$
as $du=\tanh x\,dx-dy$ and $dv=e^y\cosh^{-2}x\,dx+e^y\tanh x\,dy$ then we've got
$du^2=\tanh^2 x\,dx^2-2\tanh x\,dxdy+dy^2$ and $dv^2=e^{2y}\cosh^{-4}x\,dx^2+2e^{2y}\cosh^{-2}x\tanh x\,dxdy+e^{2y}\tanh^2 x\,dy^2$
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
f^*g_{-1}&=&du^2+e^{2u}dv^2\\
&=&\tanh^2 x\,dx^2-2\tanh x\,dxdy+dy^2 +e^{-2y}\cosh^2x \Big(e^{2y}\cosh^{-4}x\,dx^2+2e^{2y}\cosh^{-2}x\tanh x\,dxdy+e^{2y}\tanh^2 x\,dy^2\Big)\\
&=&dx^2+(1+\sinh^2x)dy^2\\
&=&dx^2+\cosh^2x dy^2\\
&=&g
\end{array}
$$
Then $g$ is complete. What do you think?

Comment: (+1) Looks good!